# C# How to write xml declaration encoding value in uppercase?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

i work with server which requires the following xml declaration `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>`. Is it any `XmlSerializer` option to use uppercase for encoding value?

Comment: Why not do a toUpper by opening xml file and just change that section, using XElement, or better yet, open file, find encoding="", change its value to upper., and save

Comment: I create xml string without any xml declaration and concat correct one. But it is ugly.

Comment: Why are you working with a server that implements XML incorrectly? If it gets such a basic thing wrong, why would you want to trust it to get more important things right? I would steer well clear.

Comment: @MichaelKay You will be laugh. It is second largest Russian bank :-)

Comment: Well, be prepared for a rough ride. If they require the encoding in upper-case, it suggests they are using a home-brew XML parser that probably has many other bugs as well (because they can't have run it through the W3C conformance test suite). And basically, if they aren't using conformant XML tooling, then you can't do so either. Standards are there for a reason...

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @mahlatse No, i don't

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom class:

```
        class CustomUTF8Encoding : UTF8Encoding
        {
            public override string HeaderName => base.HeaderName.ToUpper();
            public override string WebName => base.WebName.ToUpper();
            public override string BodyName => base.BodyName.ToUpper();
        }
```

and then use it:

```
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(output, new CustomUTF8Encoding())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Xml Linq

```
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root></Root>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The fact that Linq (like any conformant XML parser) accepts upper-case encoding names doesn't help someone who's looking for a serializer that generates upper-case encoding names.

Comment: Any xml serialization method can be added to the root node in my code.

Comment: But the question is asking whether there's a serialization method that writes the encoding in upper case.